# Spring-boot actuator: only some endpoints work

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, endpoint, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to implement spring-boot actuator for the first time but I've noticed that:

1. It only works if I specify the version, otherwise not;
2. Only a few endpoints works among those declared by the /actuator endpoint response.

This is the dependencies I've inserted in my pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-docs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

This is my application.properties:

```
#info for Spring Boot Actuator
info.app.name=Spring Sample Application
info.app.description=Application to demonstrate Spring REST HATEOAS and Actuator
info.app.version=1.0.0
```

When I make this http request:

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator
```

it returns me:

```
{"links":[{"rel":"self","href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator"},{"rel":"loggers","href":"http://localhost:8080/loggers"},{"rel":"env","href":"http://localhost:8080/env"},{"rel":"info","href":"http://localhost:8080/info"},{"rel":"heapdump","href":"http://localhost:8080/heapdump"},{"rel":"mappings","href":"http://localhost:8080/mappings"},{"rel":"metrics","href":"http://localhost:8080/metrics"},{"rel":"configprops","href":"http://localhost:8080/configprops"},{"rel":"autoconfig","href":"http://localhost:8080/autoconfig"},{"rel":"beans","href":"http://localhost:8080/beans"},{"rel":"auditevents","href":"http://localhost:8080/auditevents"},{"rel":"trace","href":"http://localhost:8080/trace"},{"rel":"health","href":"http://localhost:8080/health"},{"rel":"dump","href":"http://localhost:8080/dump"},{"rel":"docs","href":"http://localhost:8080/docs"}]}
```

Among these links, only [/health](http://localhost:8080/health) and [/info](http://localhost:8080/info) seem to work.
In fact, when I ask for [/health](http://localhost:8080/health) it returns:

```
{"status":"UP"}
```

When I ask for [/info](http://localhost:8080/info) it returnes:

```
{"app":{"description":"Application to demonstrate Spring REST HATEOAS and Actuator","name":"Spring Sample Application","version":"1.0.0"}}
```

How comes that all the other endpoints gives me **Whitelabel error page**?

Comment: For starters stop mixing versions of the framework. Remove the `<version>` tag from the `spring-boot-starter-actuator` to have the proper one.

Comment: I've introduced the question just saying that I don't understand why it doesn't work without <version> tag, as it is autogenerated by Spring Initializr.

Comment: It should work without a version (else you are building in a wrong way) and next to that if you choose to include a version NEVER mix versions of a framework (regardless of the framework).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to see the logs when you try other endpoints. It says

```
Full authentication is required to access actuator endpoints. Consider adding Spring Security or set 'management.security.enabled' to false.
```

I guess this is self explanatory. Configure atleast basic auth or set the above mentioned property to `false`.

Whitelabel error page that you see also says

```
 There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).
```

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html) is the link for the doc related to this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was getting **404** *Whitelabel Error Page* because only `/actuator/health` and `/actuator/info` are the only endpoints enabled by default (as mentioned on the [Spring Boot Actuator documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints))

To enable the other endpoints I ended up adding this configuration to my `application.yml`:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: info, health, loggers, logfile, configprops
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a posting at Baeldung where it says

> Unlike in previous versions, Actuator comes with most endpoints disabled. ([Link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators#2-important-changes))

So add `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*.` to your `application.properties`.